# Enumerated constants property does not stream

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Given the following type declaration:

```
  TMyEnum = (onehundred,twohundred,threehundred);
  TMyEnum2 = (Aonehundred = 100 , Atwohundred = 200 , Athreehundred = 300);

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyEnum: TMyEnum;
    FMyEnum2: TMyEnum2;
  published
    property MyEnum: TMyEnum read FMyEnum write FMyEnum;
    property MyEnum2: TMyEnum2 read FMyEnum2 write FMyEnum2;
  end;
```

using TStream.WriteComponent does not stream MyEnum2. Does anybody know why that is, and if this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of the streaming system. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Published_Members) says (emphasis mine):

> Some properties, although publishable, are not fully supported by the streaming system. These include properties of record types, array properties of all publishable types, and properties of **enumerated types that include anonymous values**. If you publish a property of this kind, the Object Inspector will not display it correctly, nor will the property's value be preserved when objects are streamed to disk.

You can't workaround that easily and would need to provide your own [custom streaming](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_Methods_to_Store_and_Load_Property_Values).

Comment: I knew about record types and array properties - enumerated types with anonymous values was new to me. I wonder then why Delphi allows those types in a published section anyway, or at least it could give a warning in such cases.

Comment: I'm not really much of an expert on what `published` really means, but it does mean more than just *automatically streamed*. Anyway, it is what it is. As for your enum, it looks awfully like an `Integer` to me. I can't really see what an enum does for you here.

Comment: published means, that Delphi Generates RTTI for the types in a published section. But, as I have discovered in my question, this is not true for all types. Hence I think the compiler should at least emit a warning, as the intention for putting something in a published section is to have RTTI for those types, which in turn is a requirement for the streaming system. Apart from the generated RTTI published is exactly the same as public AFAIK.

Comment: @iamjoosy generating RTTI is not the same as being able to stream

Comment: but the Delphi streaming system needs (oldschool) RTTI in order to automatically stream properties.

Answer (score 2):

Like David says, `TMyEnum2` has anonymous values and that is why the streaming mechanism can't handle the type properly. You could indeed provide your own custom streaming, or you could simply omit the enum (giving up a little type safety) and use an `Integer` and constants:

```
type
  TMyEnum = (onehundred, twohundred, threehundred);
  TMyEnum2 = type Integer;

const
  Aonehundred = 100; 
  Atwohundred = 200; 
  Athreehundred = 300;
```

Now you can use and stream `TMyEnum2` (after a rename to something useful) as you like.