# Delphi properties based on sets of subrange types are not streamed correctly to DFM file

Tags: delphi, vcl

Consider the following code:

```
type
  TColors = (Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange);  // base type
  TMyColors = Green..Orange;                     // subrange type
  TAllowedColors = set of TMyColors;             // set based on the subrange above

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FAllowedColors: TAllowedColors;
  published
    property AllowedColors: TAllowedColors read FAllowedColors write FAllowedColors;
  end;
```

Once installed into a design time package, Object Inspector correctly shows the property AllowedColors:

[image: Allowed colors are correctly shown]

Please notice that Green and Yellow are both set. Now, after saving the form and inspecting the DFM file, that's what I get:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ...
  object MyComponent1: TMyComponent
    AllowedColors = [Red, Blue]
    Left = 80
    Top = 56
  end
end
```

Notice that the IDE is saving AllowedColors **incorrectly as [Red, Blue] instead of [Green, Yellow]**. Somehow it is using the ordinality of the subrange type when streaming but then it uses the base type, instead of the subrange type (although Green should be equal to 2 - not 0 - in either case).

Is this the expected behavior or a known issue?
Is there any workaround other than taking care of the streaming to/from the DFM file myself?

PS: Tested in Delphi 10.2.3 and 10.3.3

Comment: No, this is not expected behavior. What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've just edited to include the information. Tested in 10.2.3 and 10.3.3 with same results. Thanks

Comment: Although not literally the same, I suspect the reason is the [same as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332072/2292722)

Comment: The VCL's own `TBorderStyle` is a subrange of the `TFormBorderStyle` enum, and `TBorderStyle` properties stream just fine in `TScrollBox`, `TForm`, etc. However, `TBorderStyle` does begin with `bsNone` (0), so that could be the deciding factor. Enums generally have to be sequential and start with 0 in order to have proper RTTI generated for them. So that is probably the same when streaming subranges, too.